# Why create_at time generated from mongodb is different from actual localtime time?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datetime, timezone

I am now using the default created_at feature given by nodejs and mongodb.

But the thing is the actual time i created is different from the value return from server when created.

```
 {
                "_id": "615dbc9580b0913c58e32f41",
                "createdAt": "2021-10-06T15:11:17.740Z",
                "note": "I discount because i am bored",
                "services": [
                    null,
                    null
                ],
                "items": [],
                "total_amount": 12000
            }
```

In the above example , The time i created is `2021-10-06 10:10pm` bit there is a big differnet from the return date time which is `2021-10-06T15:11:17.740Z` how can i change this behavior

Comment: Are you looking at a wrong record? Mongodb certainly does not set this field by itself. Whatever value you see, it was provided by the application.

Comment: local time of what? server? your client machine? Are you sure server has same timezone as your client machine or wherever you are comparing the local time with?

Comment: mongodb likes to retain datetime data in UTC.  The createdAt value is in Zulu time - you can tell because it ends with the letter 'Z' - 2021-10-06T15:11:17.740Z.  Your local time will be offset by the timezone you live in.  If you encounter a datetime with a specific offset it will be obvious - like 2021-10-06T10:11:17.740-5:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in the America/Los_Angeles time zone (Pacific Daylight time in early October) your time `2021-10-06 22:10` is the same as `2021-10-06T15:10Z` -- the Z means UTC.

So, if your diagnosis of the time shift is correct there's a one minute, seventeen second skew between the clock you used to get the `10:10pm` time and the one that was used to generate the timestamp in your object.

Honestly, that seems unlikely. It's quite hard to rig a server these days without [NTP](http://www.ntp.org/) time synchronization.

Comment: Pacific daylight time is UTC-7, so 10pm PDT would be 5am UTC the next day.  The times noted would indicate eastern Asia.